# Clarification about Event Producer in StreamInsight

Tags: c#, .net

I need a small clarification about `StreamInsight`, I know by doc's that `StreamInsight` can handle multiple concurrent Events. But will the event producer be a separate function, for ex: I need to watch a folder for new Files because all my sensors will write readings every day in a new file in particular drive.

**Method 1: `FileSystemWatcher`:**

These is the traditional approach where we write a service using `FileSystemWatcher` to watch a folder for new files,etc.. Upon receiving event from `FileSystemWatcher` il perform some operations on these files.

**How to do these using `StreamInsight`???**

I came know that using `IObservable` i can push events to `StreamInsight`. But is there anything to watch folder is `StreamInsight` like `FileSystemWatcher`. OR In order to raise events to `StreamInsight` do we need to use `FileSystemWacther`?

Any suggestion regarding these is highly appreciated.

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an IObservable input adapter that utilises the file system watcher, raising a new event when files change or are added. There's no out of the box support for this, you have to create your own adapter or check out the samples on MSDN.

You then create a query that observes the input adapter to process the changes.